# displaying complex type in asp.net mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two model classes:

SummaryOp

which looks like:

```
public class SummaryOp
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SummaryPT> Input { get; set; }
    public List<SummaryPT> Output { get; set; } 
}
```

and SummaryPT whch looks like:

```
public class SummaryPT
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, SummaryPT> Childs { get; set; }   
}
```

I fill this class with information in the controller. whats the best way to display (Name and TypeName) for each childs in my view?
Since there might be unknown number of childs i got confused here. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the best way is display templates. Here is a [pretty good example](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) that shows how to build both display and editor templates.

Comment: that only displays one level right, i need to display the childs as well which is where i am having problem

Comment: Displaying the children is a recursive action right? So placing the same `Html.DisplayFor` in the **template**, and sending in the child list, would accomplish that.

Comment: @Bravo11 , michael is write , use displayfor extension recursively by checking childs property's length

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
@foreach (var pt in Model) {
    @: <div><span>@pt.Name</span> <span>@pt.TypeName</span>
}
```

Comment: foreach goes only one level down thats what i was doing, the child might have a child and it doesn't work there, instead i wrote a function to solve this.